# How do I get all Live Candy Machines after a certain date?

Tags: solana-program, nft, candy-machine-v2

I want to extract candy machine IDs from a certain date to now and then display the Candy machine information by candy machine ID.

```
curl http://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getProgramAccounts",
    "params": [
      "cndy3Z4yapfJBmL3ShUp5exZKqR3z33thTzeNMm2gRZ",
      {
        "encoding": "jsonParsed",
        "filters": [
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```